# Dead Java Thread and Native OS Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some search threads which are storing results on them. I know when thread starts JVM native code proxies the request to create new native thread on the OS. This requires some memory outside of the JVM. What happens when the thread dies and I keep reference to it and use it as POJO. Does it still exist somewhere as native thread to OS (and use memory outside jvm) ?

Comment: new os threads are still running within the java (jvm) process. dont confuse threads with processes.

Comment: You should store anything in a Thread. e.g. like Futures and ExecutorServices, the future can store a value even if the thread is doing something else or not running.  i.e. you should design your system so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry I was asking specifically what happens to OS thread when corresponding java thread dies, but it is not collected due to some references. And from Answer of JB Nizet I understand that OS thread stops existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An OS thread is actually created and started when `Thread.start()` is called, and it stops existing when the thread stops running. Whether the Java object of type Thread, used to start the thread, is garbage-collected or not doesn't change anything.